# How to access a data key?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a `GridView` with textboxes in its cells. A JavaScript function is called on changing textbox's contents. I want to pass to the function a data key of the row to which the textbox belongs, but don't know how I can do that.

The following gives me an error message:

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtWFShipDate" runat="server"
        Text='<%#Eval("StrShipDate") %>' BorderStyle="None" Width="80%"
        CssClass="date"
        onchange="JSSaveWorkflowChanges(this, '<%# Eval("BookStemCommon") %>');">
 </asp:TextBox>
```

`BookStemCommon` is the data key name.

Comment: The error is "The server tag is not well formed."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
onchange='<%# string.Format("JSSaveWorkflowChanges(this, \"{0}\");", Eval("BookStemCommon")) %>'
```

or a better and safer way using [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) to properly encode the value that will be passed to the javascript function:

```
onchange='<%# string.Format("JSSaveWorkflowChanges(this, {0});", new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Eval("BookStemCommon"))) %>'
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am getting an error though:error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'JavaScriptSerializer' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @dpreznik, it is defined in the `System.Web.Script.Serialization` namespace. So either prefix it with it or define this namespace globally in your web.config. Also make sure that you have referenced the `System.Web.Extensions.dll` assembly to your project.